# how do I get Doctrine or Symfony to generate the `extends` statement

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony 2.8.3. with Doctrine ORM 2.4.8.
I use YAML to define my datamodel.

I have a mapped superclass like so:

```
    AppBundle\Entity\Location:
        type: mappedSuperclass
        fields:
            street:
                type: string
                length: '100'
```

I derive from this superclass like so:

```
    AppBundle\Entity\Building:
        type: entity
        extends: AppBundle\Entity\Location
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                id: true
                generator:
                    strategy: AUTO
```

I now expect a Building to have both an id and a street attribute.

With `app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle` this gets me the expected PHP files. Then with `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I get a `building` database tables as expected, but it only has an `id` column and no `street` column.

Only after I change `Building.php` from

```
    class Building
```

to

```
    class Building extends Location
```

and rerun `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I get the `street` column in the `building` table.

I expected Doctrine (or Symfony) to generate this `extends` statement for me, because I specified an `extends` in de YAML source.

What am I doing wrong?

Or, how do I get Doctrine or Symfony to generate the `extends` statement?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to this: Doctrine's ORM (and by extension the Symfony bundle) will not generate the extends statement for you, this is something you will have to add and maintain manually. The reason for this is primarilly because Doctrine ORM as a project doesn't want to support ad-hoc code generation. Have a look at [this GitHub issues thread](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/282) about PSR-4 support in Doctrine to get an idea of the project maintainer's stance on this.

The entities that Doctrine generates for you are **your project's** business / domain objects so it's up to you to take responsibility for maintaining them, in this case, enforcing your class hierarchy.

Alternatively, there's nothing stopping you from extending / creating your own code generator on top of Doctrine's mappings that supports your use case.

Comment: Thanks. It's not me then :)